# Show a bijection between sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

The question is: prove that there is a bijection between sets A and B for all $n_{1}, n_{2}\in  \mathbb N_{> 0}$ and for all $k_{1}, k_{2}\in \mathbb{Z}$

$A = \left\{ {n_{1}q + k_{1}} \mid  q\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$,

$B =  \left\{ {n_{2}q + k_{2}} \mid  q\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$

Any help to define the function between both sets is appreciated !!

Comment: What are your thoughts so far? Have you tried some candidates?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Try to find a bijection of $A$ with $\Bbb Z$, for a concrete pair of $n,k$ (for example $n=2$ and $k=1$). Then try to see how that would generalize to a bijection between $A$ and $B$.